# Export GridView to Excel with exactly same style displaied on web page

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

I can export gridview data to excel ,but i cant set style of the table in excel file.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();  
        Response.Buffer = true;  
        Response.ClearContent();  
        Response.ClearHeaders();  
        Response.Charset = "";  
        string FileName =DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+".xls";  


        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";    
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {

            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }



    }
```

and my Gridview setting is this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="料號">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Part_No" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Part_No")%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="bhead" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="bbody" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End user" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Dircu" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Dircu")%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="bhead" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="bbody" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assembly" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Assfct" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Assfct")%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="bhead" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="bbody" />
    </asp:TemplateField>



    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Because i use cssclass to set my Gridview style , I dont know how to also copy the style to Excel when i export this Gridview.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You will never get the exact same layout. Your are exporting html as an xls file. This will always give different results. Better use a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution at this website : [get the exact same layout](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

I got the solution from the code below:

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e){

Response.Clear();

Response.Buffer = true;

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");

Response.Charset = "";

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())

{

    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);



    //To Export all pages

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

    this.BindGrid();



    GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

    foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)

    {

        cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;

    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

    {

        row.BackColor = Color.White;

        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)

        {

            if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)

            {

                cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;

            }

            else

            {

                cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;

            }

            cell.CssClass = "textmode";

        }

    }



    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);



    //style to format numbers to string

    string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";

    Response.Write(style);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.Flush();

    Response.End();

   } 
}
```

If you set your gridview style by cssclass like me.
You can add the style describe in here `string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";` and change `cell.BackColor =` to `cell.CssClass="textmode"` then you can get customize style.

This is the code to get the exact same layout to excel:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();  
        Response.Buffer = true;  
        Response.ClearContent();  
        Response.ClearHeaders();  
        Response.Charset = "";  
        string FileName =DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+".xls";  


        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";    
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {

            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {

                cell.CssClass = "bhead";

            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

            {
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)

                {

                    cell.CssClass = "bbody";
                }


            }


            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
            string style = @"<style> .bhead{padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background:#003d79;
    color:white;
    text-align:center; } .bbody{color:Black;
    text-align:center;
    background:#d7ffee;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #fff;}</style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

            Response.End();
        }




    }
```

I hope this could help some people who have the same problem.